# Split, reorder, concat inline

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to split a cell, reorder the pieces and recombine.

How do I do that inline?

For example:

```
| name        | reordered name |
| Page,Larry  | Larry Page     |
| Brin,Sergey | Sergey Brin    |
```

How can I do this?

I know that:

```
=SPLIT(A2, ",")
```

will split the values into the next two columns and I know that I can concatenate values with:

```
=CONCATENATE(A2, " ", B2)
```

How do I bring these things together in a single formula?

Can I access the values from `SPLIT` and reorder them?

I know I can do:

```
=CONCATENATE(SPLIT(A2))
```

(but obviously that is stupid).

In Ruby I would just do something like:

```
def reorder_name(cell)
  names = cell.split(",")
  "#{names[1]} #{names[0]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Script

In Google Apps Script, a custom function like this would work:

```
function reorder_name(cell) {
  var names = cell.split(",");
  return names[1] + ' ' + names[2];
}
```

#### Spreadsheet Functions

If you've got `Lastname, Firstname` in `A1`, this spreadsheet function will render `Firstname Lastname`:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,50)) &" " &TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1))
```

If you want to go from `Firstname Lastname` to `Lastname, Firstname`:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,50)) &", " &TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1))
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work. Out of curiosity, is there a way to write this inline on a spreadsheet without defining the function in the script editor?

Answer (score 0):

Shorter formula version:

```
=index(split(A1,","),,2)&" "&index(split(A1,","),,1)
```