# Split and rejoin names names with query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm using a function to get some information I need from one sheet.

`=QUERY( COE_ALL!A:Z, "SELECT B where K = 'Jeremy' order by A ", 0)`

The problem is that the names that are populated come in as "Firstname Lastname" (like "John Smith") and I need them to come in with the QUERY as "Smith, John" with the comma.

I can't edit the original sheet that the data is coming from, but I need this changed so I can reference a master sheet with that format.

Comment: Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding any private or confidential information) and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split, reorder, concat inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704431/split-reorder-concat-inline)

Comment: Which column the names value? Column K?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(
 QUERY(COE_ALL!A:Z, "select B where K = 'Jeremy' order by A", 0), " "), 
 "select Col2,Col1", 0)),,999^99)), " ", ", "))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
=query({COE_ALL!B:B, arrayformula(query(arrayformula(split(COE_ALL!K:K," ")),"Select Col1") & ", " & query(arrayformula(split(COE_ALL!K:K," ")),"Select Col2"))},"Select Col1,Col2 where Col2 like '%Jeremy%'")
```